# Inserting data into Oracle

Tags: oracle, informix, trim

I am trying to migrate a DB from Informix to Oracle.Informix had an option like while inserting into a table if the size of the value exceeds the column length then Informix automatically trims the data.But Oracle does not support this and always throws an exception.Is there a way to prevent and allow trim or we have to respect religiously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic trimming of data in Oracle, you have to trim it explicitly yourself e.g.

```
insert into mytable (id, text) values (123, substr(var,1,4000));
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does support a variety of SQL functions which trim variables.  I suspect the one you'll want is 'SUBSTR()'.   The problem is that you will need to specify the desired length explicitly.  In this example T23.WHATEVER is presumed to be VARCHAR2(30) and T24.TOO_LONG_COLUMN is, er, longer:

```
insert into t23
  (id
    , whatever)
select pk_col
       , substr(too_long_col, 1, 30)
from t42
/
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as Tony's suggestion, you can use a CAST

```
select cast ('1234' as varchar2(3)) a
from dual
```

If you are doing data migration, look into [DML Error Logging](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/DmlErrorLogging_10gR2.php)

Having all your non-conformant data put into a corresponding table with the failure reason is positively dreamy.